# Field norm of $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero that contains a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity. Pick $a$ such that $K=F(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is a cyclic extension of $F$ of degree $n$. Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $Gal(K/F)$. Is there is a nice form for $N_{K/F}:K\rightarrow F$ other than

$$ N_{K/F}(\alpha)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma^{i}(\alpha)$$

I feel like cyclic extensions are often studied and I can't seem to find the correct reference. If anyone could point me in the right direction with a reference that would be great.

Nothing is wrong with that form. Though it isn't super useful for me here. I want to make explicit computations with a valuation on $F$ extending to $K$ and a division algebra over $F$. I haven't been very successful with this formula and we just wondering if there was another well known one?

In particular I am interested in using this form to show the extension is unramified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m sure you are aware of the fact that the norm of $a$ is also, up to sign, the constant in the characteristic polynomial of $a$ in $K$ (not the minimal polynomial). It’s also the determinant of $a$ in the regular representation. That is, $z\mapsto za$ is an $F$-linear transformation of the $F$-vector space $K$, and has a determinant, which is independent of the $F$-basis you choose for $K$. That’s the $K$-over-$F$ norm of $a$. So you don’t need a Galois group to calculate the norm.